# Could not resolve dependencies for project org.thingsboard:application:jar:3.3.0-SNAPSHOT

Tags: maven, iot, thingsboard

Want install ThingsBoard Community Edition on windows
when insatll maven this error appear

Could not resolve dependencies for project org.thingsboard:application:jar:3.3.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.thingsboard:dao:jar:tests:3.3.0-SNAPSHOT in central

How can solve this problem [image]

Comment: still building... but 1st guess: try the `release-3.2` branch (as documented) (not the master SNAPSHOT/report at github)

Comment: in order to build the snapshot, you need access & to setup https://repo.thingsboard.io/ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install jdk add it in path
go to directory path run cmd then mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
if error happend run mvn clean install -Dskiptests